# 左右ウィンドウの切り替えをコマンドで行いたい

Tags: emeditor

タブを有効にしたまま、別文書どうしで新しいグループを作って左右のウィンドウ表示にして比較することがあります。

この場合、左の文書から右の文書に（あるいはその逆に）切り替えることをコマンドで表現できないでしょうか。

[次の文書] コマンド
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4245);

ではタブ同士の切り替えになってしまいます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その状態からアクティブな文書を切り替えたいのであれば

```
editor.OpenFile( strFileName );
```

で切り替えが可能です。
OpenFile()は、ファイルがオープン済みであればそれをアクティブにするだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。特定のファイル同士の場合、strFileName を指定して、上記のとおりでうまくいきました。ただ、毎回異なるファイル同士を比較したいため、ファイル名を指定せずに切り替えを行いたいのですが、そのような方法はありますでしょうか。[右のウィンドウ] コマンド　のようなものがあればいいのですが。

Comment: やるとしたら、最近使ったファイルの一覧 editor.QueryStringByID( nID ); で nID = 4609, 4610 でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。editor.QueryStringByID( 4609 ); と editor.QueryStringByID( 4610 ); を交互に実行することで、最後に開いた二つのファイルを互いに行き来する（アクティブになる）ことができました。